# Html :Adjusting alignment of heading and <p>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have  very simple scenario  but  i am  really stuck with it and need your help please .

this is what i have to do . [image]

This is a div with righ and bottom border and and image in  its top . I have to display text same as this one . For this i  am using  bootstrap like this

```
<div class="span4" >

      <h1 class="BoldText">
        <a href="#">GET  A QUOTE</a>
      </h1>
      <span class="SimpleText">
         INSERT TEXT HEREINSERT TEXT HEREIN-SERT TEXT HEREINSERT TEXT HEREINSER
       </span>

</div>
```

now problem is that i have to show it in middle of box , `if i set margin-left to h1 and   <span>` tag this is how it looks like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBbsX.png)  padding  also does not  work here . will someone guide me how do i adjust it  . it seems simple but i am really unable to get it .

Answer (score 1):

I would set widths:
http://jsfiddle.net/4YUtW/

```
.span4 {
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #666;
}

h1 {
    width:226px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;



}
.SimpleText {
    width:226px;
    display:block;
text-align:justify;
    margin:0 auto;

}
```

but, there are probably better solutions... Of course, you will have to change values to fit your needs.

Comment: in this way will it look fine if we switch to responsive mode ?

Comment: Test it, don't know how your mobile layout looks... however - you can always tweak it with media queries?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up your CSS  as such:

```
#img {
    background:transparent url('http://thebuzzdoha.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/fifa-world-cup-wallpaper-hd.jpg') top center no-repeat;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
}

.span4 {
    border:1px dotted Black;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:400px;
    text-align:center;
}

.span4 a {
    color:Black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.SimpleText {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:70%;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

You can see this here->http://jsfiddle.net/5KjXq/

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

So, if you're not particularly attached to using `bootstrap`, doing this in pure `html` and `css` is relatively simple and usually a whole lot easier to read than the bootstrap spit-out code. I have made a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6aJJ5/1/. Hope that helps!